# I don't know how to store an array of object with mysql/node correctly

Tags: mysql, node.js, nuxt.js

I tried to make a table where i can register list of items. Actually everything is working, except array-object storage.

I tried a LOOOT of things on it,
Blob format on my sql- but i can't get the data back in front(nuxt) with .JSON() (.JSON() is not recognized) with this method. [Convert Buffer Data](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/convert-buffer-to-json-nodejs)

I tried to store it as a JSON format but it's not recognized by mysql.

Now I put it on a TEXT format on my sql (but when i call back the data i only get [object Object]- can't get through it in front or in the back.

I'd like to store something like

```
[
{"quantity":"2","content":
{"id":21,"reference":"LEG080276","designation":"cadre saillie mozaic blanc 2x6/8 modules 2x3 postes - prof 50mm","description":"sens de montage (horizontal)  nombre de modules (12)"}
},

{"quantity":"2","content":
{"id":6,"reference":"LEG080260L","designation":"voyant 2 modules 0.03w pour support batibox 1 poste ","description":null}
}
]
```

This is the call route in node.js- The list (array of objects) should be stored in content

```
router.post('/list', function getApi(req, res) {
    const {user_id, to_uuid, content, message, list_name, status}= req.body;
    db.query(`INSERT INTO list (user_id, to_uuid, content, message, list_name, status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)`, [user_id, to_uuid, content, message, list_name, status], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(`Erreur lors de l'enregistrement de la liste`);
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.status(200).send('Liste Enregistrée');
    });
  });
```

is there someone who's have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you considered using an `Associative_entity` ? [Example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Comment: even with an associative_entity, i would need to register object/array, so right now i can't with my trouble

Comment: json stringify it, then json parse it on the way out or normalise your tables and use joins, plug.. use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/autorm it will handle all that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made it!!!

I registered array of objects (which was stringified) as a text format in mysql workbench!

it worked!!

```
this.$axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/list/', {
                'user_id': this.$auth.user[0].user_id,
                'to_uuid':  this.$store.state.list.to_user.user_id,
                'content': JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.list.finalList),
                'message': this.message,
                'list_name': this.name,
                'status': "en attente"
                 })
```

this part is when i post the stringified array on content

```
async created(){
  const listReceived = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/listReceived/${this.$auth.user[0].user_id}`)
  const usersList = await this.$axios.$get("/api/users")
  
  listReceived.forEach(element => {
    const userdata=usersList.filter((post)=>post.user_id===element.user_id)
    const userSelected={
      listId:element.list_id,
      listName:element.list_name,
      message:element.message,
      status:element.status,
      content: JSON.parse(element.content),
      nickname:userdata[0].nickname
    }
          this.finalList.push(userSelected)
    })
```

this part is when i get the stringified array - I JSON.parse it on content

Comment: nice that you got it to work, if you can put in some relevant code, it can benefit other people who are running into this same issue